# When exactly are UIViewController elements ( created via IB in Main.storyboard ) initiated/loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, interface-builder, instruments

I have, in my viewController, about 15 buttons created via Interface Builder in Main.storyboard and the rest of my buttons I created programmatically. To avoid delay, I sent most of the stuff to background thread, but all the UI stuff ,including the 15 buttons, not since they are not thread safe. I would like to know when exactly are these 15 buttons loaded. Is it before `viewDidLoad`, in between `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`, etc? Moreover, since I am getting still some delay and screen freezing I tried to initialize most of the stuff of this UIViewController in a method and called this method in AppDelegate so that I move the time consuming task to when the app launch ( and there really seems to be  a increase in performance and print statements really show most of the heavy code is being called on app launch instead of when I present the view controller).

However, there is still a initial heavy loading every time I get this viewController for the first time. When I come back to the rootViewController and go back again to this ViewController (through `presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion:nil` on rootViewController and `self.dismissViewController(animated:false, completion:nil)` on ViewController ), there is no freezing anymore for all the posterior times I access it (Which is the source of all my pain... I don't understand why is it only taking time the first time I access the ViewController and not in all the other times I access it after the first time, even though all the `viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear` have no code except the super class ones that are required ).

So, all of this led me to question whether this initial heavy loading might come from the elements created via Interface Builder. It is the only possible reason I can think of to explain this behavior. Here is the Instruments screenshot showing the behavior where there is a heavy loading the first time I access viewController and only tiny peeks that do not affect the UI at all  (which is what I desire) every other time I accessed it posteriorly to the aforementioned first time.
   [Instruments Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkq8s.png)

Answer (score 1):

**initWithNibName:bundle** will get called before the nib is loaded.It is a message sent to a view (or window) controller in order to create the controller

**initWithCoder** will be called during loading from a storyboard (only storyboard).This is a message sent to every object in an archive in order to unarchive it.

**awakeFromNib** will be called after the nib is loaded.It is a message sent to every object in the nib after all of the objects in the nib have been fully loaded, after connecting all of their outlet connections in that nib.